# Success probability of naive monte carlo algorithm for primality testing

Tags: algorithm, probability, montecarlo, number-theory

Consider the following naive monte Carlo algorithn for primality testing of a number n.

```
isPrimeMonteCarlo(n,t){
/*
 * Take an integer n as input and check wheather it is prime or not
 * using the naive monte carlo method.
 * If the number is prime return True else return False.
 * */
if(n<=1)
    return False
m = sqrt(n);
for i = 1 to t:
    j = random()%m+2
    if n%j==0:
        return False
return True
}
```

Find the value of t such that the algorithm produces the correct output with high probability?

What i could come up with so far:

Assume n is non prime, the algorithm will fail when it outputs that n is prime.This happens when no number j gives n%j==0.
j is chosen from [2,sqrt(n)+2].
We want j such that j does not divide n in any of the t iterations.

Any such j must be a divisor of n.
The problem reduces to finding the number of divisors of n such that they are <= sqrt(n)+2.
I am not able to find a bound on this number.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please use a spelling checker; correct the title, too.

Comment: The question you seem to be asking might be better on a maths forum without the code. I tried looking around from http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053062/upper-limit-for-the-divisor-function but that's not quite the same question; https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/09/23/the-divisor-bound/ has other bounds for it

Comment: IIRC, half of the divisors of N should be < sqrt(N).

Comment: The total number of divisors is determined by the tau(n) function.  unfortunately, the only practical way I know of to determine it is to factor N.